# How can I resolve this runtime error "Multiple HTTP implementations were found on the classpath" using software.amazon.awssdk.http.service.impl

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-ssm

Im having trouble resolving the following runtime error: "Multiple HTTP implementations were found on the classpath. To avoid non-deterministic loading implementations, please explicitly provide an HTTP client via the client builders, set the software.amazon.awssdk.http.service.impl system property with the FQCN of the HTTP service to use as the default, or remove all but one HTTP implementation from the classpath"

I have the following two dependencies in my gradle.build :

```
implementation 'software.amazon.lambda:powertools-parameters:1.12.3'
implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:sns:2.15.0'
```

They both seem to use the default HTTP client and compiler cannot determine which one to use. See below the declaration and use of them in code:

```
private static SsmClient = SsmClient.builder().region(Region.of((region == null) ? Regions.US_EAST_1.getName() : region)).build();

private static SSMProvider ssmProvider = ParamManager.getSsmProvider(client);

static SnsClient sns = SnsClient.builder().credentialsProvider(DefaultCredentialsProvider.builder().build())
      .region((region == null) ? Region.US_EAST_1 : Region.of(region)).build();
```

I cannot remove one from the class path since I need both for my application and I have not succesfully been able to define an awssdk client via the builders.

I tried this but still got same runtime error:

```
client = SsmClient.builder().httpClientBuilder(new SdkHttpClient() {
   @Override
   public void close() {

   }

   @Override
   public ExecutableHttpRequest prepareRequest(HttpExecuteRequest request) {
      return null;
   }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same problem.
The blog post about AWS SDK turned out to be useful:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/aws-sdk-for-java-2-x-released/

The following one was best in my use case:

```
System.setProperty("software.amazon.awssdk.http.service.impl","software.amazon.awssdk.http.urlconnection.UrlConnectionSdkHttpService");
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will have to exclude one of the versions of `http-client` in your `pom`

```
implementation('<dependency>') {
    exclude group: '<group>', module: '<module>'
}
```

where `dependency` is one of:

```
'software.amazon.lambda:powertools-parameters:1.12.3'
'software.amazon.awssdk:sns:2.15.0'
```

You can run `gradle dependencies` to see the dependency tree to figure out which one you want to exclude from

Comment: I cant exclude one of the dependencies since I need both in my application. power tools provides a caching feature for my SSM client so cannot get rid of it. Is there a way to explicitly create the clients so that conflicts can be resolved?

Comment: you wouldnt be excluding the entire dependency, just the transitive http-client which you dont need both of on your classpath

Answer (score 0):

Can you try explicitly setting below to ensure specific http is used.

```
System.setProperty("software.amazon.awssdk.http.service.impl", "software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheSdkHttpService");
```